# base manifest is missing android:icon. You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am releasing my android app project on play store. So After reading some blogs I decided to put that app for testing to some limited users and then publish the app. But when I uploaded the package of my app in play store then an error in red line comes like:

```
Your base manifest is missing android:icon. nullLearn more about android:iconnull. 
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.
```

[image: See the error here]

Why this error is popping, I already done setting my icon. And also what is the meaning of this line `"com.example" is restricted.`.

Comment: Share your app manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1: Your base manifest is missing the `android:icon` attribute

Open your app's manifest file, go to the `<application>` tag. Inside the `<application>` tag, you need to set your app's icon with the `android:icon` attribute. See the below code for a reference:

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

#### Issue 2: You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted

The package name is the unique identifier for your application. "com.example" is the default package name for Android applications so you need to change your application package name. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-package-name-in-android) to change the app package name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload your apk to play store using com.example package name. Your package name should be unique in nature, you need to change your package name

[Change package name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/6245921)